# What type of comma rule is this called?

Tags: commas

> The drawing depicts two well dressed kings, their gowns and accessories indicating their wealth and power.

I believe the comma is used correctly.

Comment: It's used to set off the absolute clause. Another example is _His hair flying in the wind, the boy raced across the beach._ Here, the absolute clause is fronted. A lone adjective is occasionally used in an absolute construction: _Exhausted, they collapsed on the ground._

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“She ran… , her nose pressed against the glass” Are the actions simultaneous or consecutive?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/287209/she-ran-her-nose-pressed-against-the-glass-are-the-actions-simultaneous-or)

Comment: Are you looking for an actual _name_ of this specific use of a comma? Like how having a comma before the word _and_ in a list (like “X, Y`,` and Z”) is called the ‘Oxford comma’? ’Cause I don’t think there is a name for this one.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking at several grammar blogs. It helps out a lot now that this phrase was referred to as an absolute clause. Its clearer now that I can refer to this issue whenever I see it.

Answer (score 2):

The comma here is employed to bracket off a syntactic supplement—a piece of the sentence which is not a constituent of the main clause. In this case, the supplement is an absolute clause.

This bracketing is more or less equivalent to bracketing with parentheses or dashes; it's the same as comma-bracketing the name of the person you're addressing or a non-restrictive relative clause, or an apposition.

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining it! I can see how it's sort of like an apposition

Comment: @Crispy Kreme Fan Its function is very different from that of an apposition, though both add information to the matrix sentence, and both need setting off to show that they are not part of the matrix sentence. 'Parentheticals' is probably a hypernym for these and other structures.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks Edwin. Would you say that using parentheses "()" is also ok to use for (their gowns and accessories...)?

Comment: A comma, a dash, a pair of parentheses – all these are valid choices. But they _do_ signal different degrees of emphasis. Your version (with the comma) is the unmarked, tagging-on-another-useful-and-relevant-bit-of-information variant. A dash highlights the statement in the absolute clause. Use of brackets hints at prior context for the statement in the absolute clause (eg a justification in answer to an earlier question, "How do you know they were men of standing?", or other context (... you need to use this sort of reasoning if you want to be a good historian [_hint_]).